# how to make customized jexl function to work with collections

Tags: kotlin, collections, jexl

I tried many ways but seemed jexl doesn't work well with collections and lambda expression. Essentially I have a list of json objects and I want to have a customized utility function set into jexl context so as the expression to be
`"filter(collections, 'a -> a.age > 10')"`  While collection is a list of Person(name, age) objects, filter is the customized function to achieve the similar filter logic in coding language while 'a-> a.age > 10" is the condition clause.
But now matter how hard I try, it seems jexl always have issues to parse the 'a -> a.age > 10" as this is lambda.
I'm getting either parsing error or undefined variable error to a point not sure if anyone achieved to write collection related customized function in jexl

Tried to have a function takes collection, either string or a condition clause not work.
Resulting always in undefined variable or parse error from jexl.

Answer (score 0):

JEXL requires a bit of configuration and customization to adapt to any use case. To allow collections (or streams) to be filtered by expressions, there is an example in [StreamTest.java](https://github.com/apache/commons-jexl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/jexl3/examples/StreamTest.java); have a look at CollectionContext and testURICollection, this should point you in the right direction.

Beware that permissions are a lot more constrained by default in JEXL 3.3 and need to be properly defined for scripts to run properly. (see [JexlPermissions](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jexl3/introspection/JexlPermissions.html))

Hope this helps.